# Linear Transformation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I was on the internet reading about linear algebra and looking for exercises when I found the following one:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ a linear transformation. Let $(u_1, \dots, u_k)$ be a base of the kernel of $f$ and $(v_1, \dots, v_r)$ a basis of the image of $f$. $\forall i=1,\dots, r$ we choose $w_j \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(w_j)=v_j$. Prove that $\mathcal{B} = (u_1, \dots, u_k, w_1,\dots, w_r )$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Write the matrix of $f$ in the basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ y en una base $\mathcal{B}'$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$ obtained completing the basis $(v_1, \dots, v_r)$ of $Im(f)$.

Comment: This question doesn't quite make sense. You say that $v_1, \cdots, v_r$ form a basis for the image $f$, i.e., they are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$, then you put them into a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @Uri Toti Do you know about rank nullity thoeorem?

Comment: I have not heard about it

Comment: How can I use the rank nullity theorem to prove this? I know that $dim(ker(f)) + dim(im(f)) = n$, isn't it? Then what?